# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.s

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

react version 18.2.0
Nextjs 13.1.5

When I try to create `onClick` to change the theme on the website. I get this Unhandled Runtime Error :

> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.s

```html
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? "dark" : ""}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nared Fuengverojsakul</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className=" bg-white px-10 dark:bg-gray-900 md:px-20 lg:px-40">
        <section className="min-h-screen">
          <nav className="py-10 mb-12 flex justify-between dark:text-white">
            <h1 className="font-burtons text-xl">PORTFOLIO</h1>
            <ul className="flex items-center">
              <li>
                <BsFillMoonStarsFill
                  onClick={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)}
                  className=" cursor-pointer text-2xl"
                />
              </li>
      </main>
    </div>
);
```

Unhandled Runtime Error :

> Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if any errors occur in the console. If so fix them and next if you are importing components that don't need server-side rendering. Use the following import type to avoid hydration errors.

```
const Comp= dynamic(() => import('path of file'), { ssr: false })
```